# Jhipster 5, saving failed when using relationship to Jhipster User

Tags: hibernate, jhipster

I am using example from https://github.com/mraible/jhipster5-demo. I used Postgresql for dev and pro. Project with entities are generated successfully.

When I create new Blog and saving, i got this error.

> Exception in com.asdev.blog.web.rest.BlogResource.createBlog() with cause = 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.asdev.blog.domain.Blog.user -> com.asdev.blog.domain.User' and exception = 'org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.asdev.blog.domain.Blog.user -> com.asdev.blog.domain.User; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.asdev.blog.domain.Blog.user -> com.asdev.blog.domain.User'

I did with jhipster 4 and worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't cross post: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipste this makes us all lose time

Comment: Sorry for cross post. Please close this thread. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is probably because the value held in the field when saving the Many side(Blog) is in an unmanaged state on JPA.
As a countermeasure, I modified Controller, you can solve by retrieving the object on the One side(User) and resetting it to the Many side field.